# 7zip tries to compress files and folder outside of the path

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, 7-zip

I use the command line of 7zip, 7za, to compress a folder, on Windows web server 2008 R2.

```
7za.exe a -tzip -r %nome_file% "C:\inetpub"
```

I expect it to compress everything inside the folder "inetpub, but it compress or tries to compress files and folders outside the path.
I have in the log file the following messages:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-1548477359-4160443295-2229684838-500\:  WARNING: Access is denied.
C:\Config.Msi\:  WARNING: Access is denied.
C:\Documents and Settings\:  WARNING: Access is denied.
```

Why? What is weird is that some of those locations do not even exist. There is no "C:\Documents and Settings\" on the "C:\" disk.

Comment: "There is no 'C:\Documents and Settings\' on the 'C:\' disk.". Yes there is. It's a normally hidden system file that is a junction with the target 'C:\Users\'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the -r.  It doesn't do what you think it does.

```
C:
cd \
7za a -tzip -mx=9 -mfb=258 -mpass=15 -mfb=258 C:\temp\filename.zip inetpub
```

(That is my preferred syntax, which makes things go a bit slower to maximize compression.)

That will create the file you ask for, using the specified subdirectory.

It seems you're thinking that -r will contain the specified subdirectory and all subdirectories under that.  Nope, that's default.  The point of -r is to search subdirectories for a file/subdirectory with the name that you specify.  So C: is being searched for something called inetpub.  You're getting Access Denied warnings as C: is being searched.  That's not the effect that you're trying to pull off.  So just get rid of -r

Comment: Thank you. So the "C:\ " in "C:\inetpub" doesn't do anything. You just change directory to go in the directory where inetpub is.

Comment: Yeah.  From some quick experimentation, I find that including a file that starts with "C:\temp\" or "\temp\" fails causes the directory of that file to be discarded, but specifying "temp\" (as a subdirectory) worked like a charm.